# Crystal Report Error in formula This field name is not known

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, windows-server-2012-r2

When I call ExportToDisk(). In some machine do well. But in some machine throw the exception.

**Exceptoion**

> **This field name is not known.**
>   Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\RPTH010_Report01 {C0D0E863-1741-4917-A455-B23347EA4FD6}.rpt:
>   **Error in formula**  <填單日期>. 
>   'numberVar RocDateNumber := {RPTH010_Report01.D01_APLDATE};'
>   **This field name is not known**.
>   **This field name is not known**.
>   Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\RPTH010_Report01 {C0D0E863-1741-4917-A455-B23347EA4FD6}.rpt:
>   **Error in formula**  <填單日期>. 
>   'numberVar RocDateNumber := {RPTH010_Report01.D01_APLDATE};'
>   **This field name is not known**.

**stack trace**

> CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
>   JcsWebSolution.Report.CRDocument.SaveToDisk()
>   mOffice.Models.Report.ASSET.RPTH010_Report01.PrintReport()
>   mOffice.Models.Report.ReportBase.PrintProcess()

**My system**

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll, v10.5.3700.0
- CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll, v10.5.3700.0
- Window Server 2012 R2
- Visual Studio 2013

I try to fixed the bug by

- Reinstall crystal report runtime SP12.
- Checking the font is in system.

And I try to print a report without formula and it can export well. And I add the concat string formula it just broken.

**My code**

```
public class result
{
  public string { get; set;}
}

public bool DoExport()
{
  List<result> test = new List<result>();
  test.Add(new result { test = "123" });

  DataTable input = ListToDataTable(test);

  input.TableName = "test";
  m_RptDataSet.Tables.Add(input);

  ReportDocument m_ReportDocument = new ReportDocument();

  m_ReportDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/RPT/test.rpt"));
  m_ReportDocument.SetDataSource(input);
  m_ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "test.pdf");

  m_ReportDocument.Close();
  m_ReportDocument.Dispose();

  m_ReportDocument = null;
}

public  DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)        
{
  PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  object[] values;

  for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)            
  {            
    PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);            
  }

  foreach (T item in list)
  {
    values = new object[props.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
      values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(values);
  }

  return dt;
}
```

**concat string formula**

> {RPTH040_Test.test} + " test Function"

But in other machine just fine. Does anyone has the same problem?

**Updated**

I test a new report which have 3 records without formula. I find that the report can export, but does not show records. So I guess the main reason is that SetDataSource() doesn't work in my machine(windows 2012 R2).
I try to add the code to Web.config.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

It still not work. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: have you checked your table structure? its not getting the required field used in formula

Comment: What's the field's data type?  Is it ever `null`?

Comment: To @craig , Its type is string.

Comment: I test a new report which have 3 records without formula.
I find that the report can export, but does not show the records.
So I guess the main reason is SetDataSource() doesn't work in the machine(windows 2012 R2).
I try to add `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>` to Web.config.
It still not work. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the main result from SCN.

> CR 10.5 (CR for VS 2008) is not compatible / tested supported with Win 2012. It is also not compatible with VS 2013.
> Upgrade CR to CR for VS 2013 (13.0).
>
> Bhushan

More detail -> [Windows server 2012 R2 SetDataSource doesn't work | SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3667925)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Crystal Report after making series of changes in the respective stored procedure, finally I found that I was using a field in my formulas which were removed from my sp (earlier this field was there when I have created the formula and then removed from the SP), so I updated my formula with proper updated field now and then its gone.